# Overriding PrimaryKeyRelatedField to serialize a null RelatedField object based on request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Can anyone suggest how I can serialize the following type of null related field to give a serialized JSON object list which isn't null on get request

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    a_fk = models.ForeignKey(ForeignObj1, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b_fk = models.ForeignKey(ForeignObj2, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ['a_fk', 'b_fk']
```

What I get/see in browsable API JSON is

```
{
   "a_fk": null,
   "b_fk": null
}
```

but the fields queryset are fetched on the browsable API form for POST request just like normal django forms

What I will like to see is the actual list of available queryset objects on those fields returned on get request, even though it's null, if I override the PrimaryKeyRelatedField **init**(), which I did, printing the fields still returned empty queryset, which means it's still treating the field as null.

I have gone through the source codes and still can't figure out how to make this happen dynamically on get request

P.S The fields have to remain null due to some business use case. Any nudge in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

my view for now looks like this

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Some.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer
```

I also have another @action getter view embedded within a separate ModelViewSet, trying to get with request as well, still returning the same null objects.

After searching for hours, I think, the appropriate question should have been, how do I create a choice iterable list from a null PrimaryKeyRelatedField, again a nudge in the right direction will be super appreciated...

Comment: What does your views.py look like?

Comment: @Wakek Zheng, I just updated my post with the view

Comment: See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/ -- define a `Serializer` subclass for each object type and in `SomeSerializer` specify `a = Obj1Serializer(many=True)`

Comment: @Mark R, what you suggested will work for a reverse relation, I am not dealing with a reverse relation case. I am dealing with a case where the fk's need to be selected in options on a form, like it can be selected on Browsable API form. So the f'k's pretty much have to be there.